# Starting services required by Rails running with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that, during production, will be launched / spawned by Passenger and Apache. My question is this: what is the best method for launching a required Ruby script / service automatically?

I'm not too clued up on the workflow of Passenger as it spawns multiple Rails handlers for the requests, but I need to only have the service running once in total.

Do I use a background job manager such as Sidekiq, delayed_job etc. or simply wrap the Ruby script in a Thread and place an initializer in the Rails config folder?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to start a script that should only have a single running instance is either through a ruby script or a rake task. For example when using sidekick:

- Create a sidekick worker called 'my_worker.rb'

  ```
  class MyWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform
      # do something
    end
  end
  ```
- Call it from a rake task like:

  ```
  require_relative '../../app/workers/my_worker'

  namespace :disruption_worker do
    desc "Schedule the My Worker in Sidekiq"
    task :schedule => :unschedule do

      MyWorker.perform_async
    end

  end
  ```

Comment: What are the benefits of using Sidekiq / another daemon tool vs adding an entry to the Ruby script to update-rc.d file (if any)?